# Colour matching with Photoshop and Canon IP7250

Tags: photoshop, printing, color-management

After having used a HP multifunction printer for some time, today I upgraded to a Canon Pixma IP7250 inkjet. I'm having serious difficulties making the prints resemble the images on screen, an issue I didn't have with the HP printer. With the Canon, they're all coming out with a strong magenta tint, especially in the shadow tones.

These are my settings in PS (CS5)

[image: printing dialog box]

I'm using what is supposed to be the right profile for matte photo paper on this printer. The profile came with the printer installation and I've been unable to find a better match.

The printer is not calibrated, but I don't think it can be that far off. Especially considering I didn't have the issues with the HP printer. What settings did I use for the HP? Just printing from OSX Preview, actually. I tried that for the Canon but the results are still magenta. So now trying to get some more control by using PS, but no luck.

My images are in Adobe RGB.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: did you disable the printers color management as suggested by the warning dialog?

Comment: Yes, it gets greyed out automatically.

Comment: You are not guaranteed to have the accuracy without a profile for specific printer-inks-paper combination.

Answer (score 1):

The setting looks fine, except perhaps turning on the black point compensation, but it probably gets turned on automatically behind the scenes anyways.

There are some things that I would try to get to the core of the problem:

- Print something with printer color management instead of PS color management. Does it come out magenta as well? If yes, the problem may be in the printer
- Try Relative Colorimetric rendering intent instead of Perceptual
- Try different paper type with appropriate profile to ensure that the problem is not in the paper/profile combination
- Run printer diagnostic, nozzle check etc.
- Try to re-download the profile or otherwise ensure that it isn't corrupted
- Double check the paper settings in the printer driver. You can get weird effects like this if the paper type is set incorrectly and the substrate receives non-optimal amount of ink

Answer (score 1):

I have just bought a Canon iP7250 and have set it up to print what I see on my screen using;

In the Quick Setup window uncheck Borderless Printing

Go to the Main Window and Color/Intensity check Manual and click Set

At the bottom of that window check 'Print a pattern for color adjustment'

From the drop down choose C M Y and the paper size etc.
Print your sheet of thumbnails, these will have the settings used for each image
Do the same for Intensity/Contrast

Choose from these two sheets the settings that are nearest to your screen image
and make the C M Y, I and C adjustments with the sliders

Go to Page Setup and choose the paper parameters you want to use
Go to Quick Setup and make sure those parameters are correct

Near the top of the QS page you will see Save. 
Use this to save all the settings and nominate them

You new named print profile will appear in the text box above the Save button.
Repeat for various the types of paper you use.

And the cost ..... Zero! lol ..... Takes longer to write it than to do it.

Cheers - Jim

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to a Canon ip8750 photo printer plus also a new Dell 2713h monitor and encountered the same issue where the prints had a slight magenta tint to them. I also used an HP all in one and although not perfect, the prints were adequate.

After lots of trial and error, I used the spyder4 calibrator to recalibrate the monitor to wide gamut. I then ran a calibrate page on the printer and I am now getting on paper what I see on the screen.

All other settings are default and I use a Mac.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. What is a 'calibrate page on the printer'?

Comment: @Jimmy on start up, the printer asked for various papers to be input and ran an auto calibration, printing off various colour profiles. I also notice that the canon printer does not offer ICC profiles, and I believe this may be the case with your printer too. In which case, only the canon papers will provide a correct colour reproduction. I have tried HP paper, and the colours are out. In my case, I truly believe, it was the monitor calibration that sorted the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I Have had the same problem with the iP7250. tried different paper, different setups, different calibrations. Contacted canon who would not admit it is the driver at fault. Using same paper and profiles at college printer (canon pro driver) on same files and get beautiful prints. Says a lot really. I'm sure they know very well the iP7250 software is broken.

Comment: A printer profile is valid only for a specific printer/ink/paper combination.  Printer profiles are not interchangeable unless it is an identical model printer using identical ink type and paper type.

Comment: To those commenting that this doesn't answer the question, it is very much an answer to the question.  It may not be a correct answer, but the answer they are giving is that it is a driver problem with the printer and it isn't possible to get acceptable results.